# how to get the web form results

Tags: webforms

I need to get the results of the web form as a block to display with the webform.

It seems views has no way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been able to get Webform information into Views in the past, but I ended up delving into the database to do so since the integration of Webform and Views is limited to submission ids and edit links, not the specific data that was entered by the user.

I found this tutorial online that might be useful for you. http://archive.org/details/DisplayWebformSubmissionDataInViews